# Hiding a paypal button added programmatically

Tags: ios, paypal, uibutton, uilabel

I add a paypal button to my code using:

```
[self addLabelWithText:@"" andButtonWithType:BUTTON_294x43 withAction:@selector(simplePayment)];
```

I have a view that pops up over it at one point.  This button stays on top of the view.  I would like it to be behind or hidden.  How would I go about hiding or removing this button and adding it back after the view is done?  I'm just not sure how to reference this.  I know there is some way to tag it etc...  Thanks.

Comment: Store it in an instance variable.

Comment: [self.buttonInstanceVariable setHidden:YES]

Comment: Ok... how I store it?  I'm a bit confused obviously.

Comment: I've tried things like this to reference it...   PayPalButtonType *btnallstates;
   
    
[btnallstates setType:BUTTON_278x43];

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it... 
I created a uibutton and assigned it to the paypal button in the method.

```
- (void)addLabelWithText:(NSString *)text andButtonWithType:(PayPalButtonType)type withAction:(SEL)action
```

Then I hide the button as needed.